# Is it (too) easy to reverse-engineer a C# .exe?

Tags: c#, wpf, obfuscation

I am about to begin writing a new Windows application from scratch.  Since it is a Windows application, the power of C#/WPF etc. would do a lot of the heavy lifting of writing it, however, I am concerned about the ease with which C# .exe files can be reverse-engineered.  I am hoping the final application will sell for $10-$30, so we are not talking Autocad or Maya prices, but just how worried should I be that someone could easily create a virtual copy?  I mean $10 is not a fortune, but it is the difference between my being able to carry on developing the application and begging on the streets.

I am wondering if I should use some kind of obfuscation.  Do these really achieve anything?  Do they simply make it harder to get good debug messages out?  Does anyone have any experience of these, and if so can anyone recommend one?

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Kind wishes ~ Patrick

Comment: In a C# .exe you have only intermediate language (IL-Code), the same code as you would write your application with VB.NET or other .NET lanuages. On the target computer the IL-code were compiled to the processor specific asm code. The IL-Code is easy to read and can extracted with ildasm.exe and can recompiled with ilasm.exe. But your variable-names are not in the IL-Code. So with a little bit brain power (and knwoledge), someone could easyly change your code.

Comment: Your best bet would be to make it a Store app. Copying and reverse enginering would still be possible but because of the store it is easier to get and pay for it.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Sorry about the duplicate. I did search but didn't find the question posted above.